# Pandas insert empty column between existing columns

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to make a csv converter with Pandas. Currently it reads a file (export.csv) and writes a new file (google.csv). I've selected the columns from the export.csv file but for the new file I want to insert a few new columns.

I'd like to insert one at the beginning of the dataframe called Date and have the same value entered (11-23-20) for each row, I'd like to add another one between ProductUrl and RetailPrice called Shippinged with no values.

Here's my code:

```
import pandas as pd

ed = pd.read_csv('export.csv')
df = ed[['ItemID', 'ProductUrl', 'RetailPrice', 'ItemName', 'ItemName', 'ItemPrimaryImageUrl', 'CategoryList', 'Manufacturer', 'GTIN', 'ProductStatus','CategoryList', 'ItemNumber']]
df.columns =['id', 'link', 'price', 'title', 'description','image_link', 'product_type','brand', 'gtin', 'availability', 'google_product_category','mpn'] 
df.to_csv('google.csv')
```

Comment: `df.insert(0, 'col_name', value_you_want_to_input)` should help you add to the dataframe. This will repeat the value at column 1 with column name as `col_name`.

Answer (score 4):

To insert a column at the specific location, you can use:

```
df.insert(loc, column, value)
```

Let's assume, your dataset is as follows:

```
>>> df

   ItemID ProductUrl  RetailPrice ItemName
0       1       aUrl          1.0    aItem
1       2       bUrl          2.0    bItem
2       3       cUrl          3.0    cItem
```

You can add a column to the beginning by using:

```
df.insert(0, 'Date', pd.Timestamp.now().strftime('%m-%d-%y'))
```

This will give you:

```
>>> df.insert(0, 'Date', pd.Timestamp.now().strftime('%m-%d-%y'))
>>> df
       Date  ItemID ProductUrl  RetailPrice ItemName
0  11-23-20       1       aUrl          1.0    aItem
1  11-23-20       2       bUrl          2.0    bItem
2  11-23-20       3       cUrl          3.0    cItem
```

Then you can add the column to the specific location with a similar insert statement.

You have two options: You can search for the column name where you want to insert, then insert. OR, you can insert to a specific location if you already know the location.

In your case, you want to insert the column between `'ProductUrl'` and  `'RetailPrice'`. The original location for `'RetailPrice'` was 3. We added a column to the beginning. So the current location for `'RetailPrice'` is 4. So you can insert the new column at position 4. Remember, columns starts from 0. So you need to insert at location 3 (0 = Date, 1 = ItemID, 2 = ProductUrl, 3 = newColumn, 4 = RetailPrice).

```
>>> df.insert(3, 'Shippinged', '')
>>> df
       Date  ItemID ProductUrl Shippinged  RetailPrice ItemName
0  11-23-20       1       aUrl                     1.0    aItem
1  11-23-20       2       bUrl                     2.0    bItem
2  11-23-20       3       cUrl                     3.0    cItem
```

Alternatively, you can use `columns.get_loc()` to get the index of any column.

Since you want to insert the column in between `'ProductUrl'` and `'RetailPrice'`, you can choose to search for the position of `'RetailPrice'` and insert at that location.

```
>>> idx = df.columns.get_loc('RetailPrice')
>>> df.insert(idx, 'Shippinged', '')
>>> df
       Date  ItemID ProductUrl Shippinged  RetailPrice ItemName
0  11-23-20       1       aUrl                     1.0    aItem
1  11-23-20       2       bUrl                     2.0    bItem
2  11-23-20       3       cUrl                     3.0    cItem
```

This will give you the new dataframe to write to `'google.csv'`

Answer (score 0):

Use [`pd.DataFrame.insert`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.insert.html):

```py
df.insert(0, 'Date', pd.Timestamp.now().strftime('%m-%d-%y'))

idx = df.columns.get_loc('ProductUrl')
df.insert(idx+1, 'Shippinged', '')
```

Comment: i think the new column has to be between `'ProductUrl'` and `'RetailPrice'` so you need to search for `'RetailPrice'` and insert at that location.

Comment: Yep, or you can just add 1 to the index. Updated. Thx.